# How to change keyboard shortcut to switch input language on Chrome OS?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, google-chrome-os, keyboard-layout, chromium-os

On Chrome OS, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> is used to change current keyboard layout.

[image]

This is very inconvenient when using a computer for programming. Usually, this keyboard shortcut is triggers the help popup. For example [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features) features in VS Code or QtCreator's [completion](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html#editing-keyboard-shortcuts). Is it possible to change the shortcut key to <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>?

[image]

Has anyone created a petition to add missing features to the Chrome OS keyboard software? Is there a user-friendly solution to the problem (command for crosh without creating your own Chromium OS distribution)?

Pressing  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> does not solve the problem.

**UPDATE:**

Damn It! Currently I am living in 2021 and they created tumbler to remap the backspace button into Google Assistant trigger, but feature with custom shortcut for keyboard layout switch still is not resolved

[image]

Comment: On `emacs` this is an issue too, as `ctrl+space` is used for another frequently used function (setting regional mark). Just as a pointer, I'm logging toward my own solution (my setup may be a bit more complicated as it entails Linux mode on ChromeOS) in https://github.com/kinu-garage/hut_10sqft/issues/926

Comment: @IsaacS Nope, this is ChromeOS specific behavior. For example, VS Code will not interrupt the Ctrl+Shift hotkey on Windows and will switch the keyboard layout correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned "emacs on ChromeOS" (I cannot modify my comment as certain time passed).